# .NET C# : HttpClient and the TaskCanceledException exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I've started using **System.Net.Http.HttpClient** and it's a great class. I'm at a point where I want to give my program's user the ability to cancel operations, for example if a bunch of HTTP requests take too long to complete. So, naturally, I've come across the **CancellationTokenSource** class and modified my calls to the async methods of HttpClient to also pass them a **CancellationToken**. In my UI code I can now "cancel that token", and indeed it interrupts whatever HTTP request was in progress at that point.

What I didn't expect, however, is that this causes the interrupted method to throw the **TaskCanceledException** exception.

Here's my question : I've looked at the MSDN documentation for **HttpClient** and I have found no mention of that exception. I suppose that is because it's a common behavior to any async method that takes a **CancellationToken**, but so far I haven't found much information about that. Can you confirm or infirm my supposition, and point me to the relevant documentation ?

My "real question" is whether I'm using the **CancellationToken** mechanism right, meaning, is that exception supposed to happen, or am I doing something wrong ?

If that exception is supposed to happen, and if it is a mechanism I can rely on, then it will simplify my code. Right now, I test my token's **IsCancellationRequested** property after each call to **HttpClient** async methods to determine if my methods should proceed or return, but with this exception, all that additional code becomes pointless.

I'm cancelling the token using this statement :

```
myCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

Comment: When you are asking "am I doing this the right way" use code instead of words to explain what you are currently doing. Code crosses all language barriers.

Comment: It's meant to throw an exception.

Comment: Scott, I agree with you, but I'm not doing anything exceptional (no pun intended). I'll see what I can do.

Comment: John : that's what I believe, but I'd like to be 100% sure, hence my request for documentation. I can't just base a software design decision on someone telling me on SO "it's supposed to do that", I'm sure you understand.

Comment: In my opinion it's really stupid if supposed behaviour throws exeptions. Completely illogical.

Answer (score 1):

[Is catching TaskCanceledException and checking Task.Canceled a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559416/is-catching-taskcanceledexception-and-checking-task-canceled-a-good-idea)

> In the .Net framework itself when you pass a [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) as a parameter you will get back a [`TaskCanceledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception(v=vs.110).aspx). I would not go against that and create my own design pattern because people who are familiar with .Net will be familiar with your code.
>
> My guideline is this: The one that cancels the token is the one that should handle the `TaskCanceledException`, so If you're using a `CancellationToken` inside your method for your own reasons, go ahead and use a `try-catch` block. **But if you get the token as a parameter, let the exception be thrown**.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2014/03/19/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/

> Don’t throw OperationCanceledException after you’ve completed the work, just because the token was signaled. Return a successful result and let the caller decide what to do next. The caller can’t assume you’re cancellable at a given point anyway so they have to be prepared for a successful result even upon cancellation.

In my opinion, `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is the easiest way to handle most interactions with the cancellationToken. Then you only need to handle the exception.

Comment: I think we're on the same page. Do you have any MSDN link regarding the TaskCancelledException as it pertains to HttpClient ?

Comment: I am not sure they document stuff which they consider as standard... you can always dig trough the sources though. E.g. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/6b9440735abc9c4e369376bca097766527971a7a/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectionCloseReadStream.cs#L21

Answer (score 1):

Throwing `TaskCanceledException` when canceled is the norm for all methods which accept a `CancellationToken` parameter. That this isn't always documented is (IMO) an oversight.

But at least there are a few docs for the overall pattern, to document the behavior in a general sense:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children

Documents also sometimes just mention `OperationCanceledException` to imply `TaskCanceledException`, since they are super- and sub-class.